# ldap_add a traves de PHP

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

mi pregunta es a cerca de añadir usuarios(uid,cn,employeeNumber..) a mi servidor LDAP a través de una herramienta PHP. Llevo varias horas buscando y no me funciona nada de lo que he visto.El servidor web (Apache en XAMPP) y el servidor ldap(que está en un CentOS 6.10) están en la misma red local.Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['login']))
    {
?>
       <form action="pruebillas.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
         <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
         <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" /><br>
       </form>
<?php    
     } else {
       $ldap_dn = "employeeNumber=".$_POST["username"].",ou=administrativos,ou=empleados,dc=project,dc=local";
       $ldap_password = $_POST["password"];
       $ldap_con = ldap_connect("192.168.1.37");
       ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

       if (!$ldap_con) { return false; }
       $r = ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password);

       // Prepare data
       $info["cn"]="John Jones";
       $info["sn"]="Jones";
       $info["mail"]="jonj@example.com";
       $info["objectclass"]="inetOrgPerson";

       // Add data to directory
       $r = ldap_add($ldap_con, "cn=John Jones,ou=limpieza,ou=empleados,dc=project,dc=local", $info);

       return true;
    }

?>
```

La autenticación funciona perfectamente,pero la operación me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Insufficient access in
>   C:\xampp\apache\seguro\pruebillas.php on line 32

Siendo la línea 32 la de

```
$r = ldap_add($ldap_con, "cn=John Jones,ou=limpieza,ou=empleados,dc=project,dc=local", $info);
```

El esquema del árbol de directorios es el siguiente:
He añadido ya varios usuarios de forma manual con archivos LDIF en el servidor, pero a través de PHP me es imposible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Este error se produce al agregar o modificar el objeto cn = Config en Open Ldap porque el usuario administrador CN no tiene suficientes privilegios para actualizar el esquema en DC

**Posible solución:**

1.- Actualizar la contraseña de olcRootDN
Ejecutar  el comando slappasswd y generará la nueva contraseña de la siguiente manera.

```
slappasswd 
Nueva contraseña: 
Vuelva a introducir la nueva contraseña: 
{} SSHA Hfpsjkt / Am2LDOndfBmPyjWyXaBk8K
```

2.- Luego ir a  /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config y editar el archivo olcDatabase = {0} config.ldif y agregar la contraseña generada después de olcRootDN

```
olcRootPW: / SS2.
```

3. Guardar el archivo y reinicia el servidor Ldap

Igual mira la documentación que es bi9en completa: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo a medias. He cambiado lo que me dijiste pero parece que no funcionó. El problema es que me estaba autenticando con usuarios de mi server LDAP, que parece que no pueden escribir a través de PHP,por eso ,he cambiado "$ldap_dn = "employeeNumber=".$_POST["username"].",ou=administrativos,ou=empleados,dc=project,dc=local";"  por  "$ldap_dn = "cn=root,dc=project,dc=local";".    Ahora al entrar con root si que me deja,pero no me gusta nada la idea de loguearme con root. Por casualidad sabrías como hacer que otros users puedan escribir? Aún así, muchas gracias

Comment: Buena, al menos podrás hacer las pruebas en ambiente de desarrollo mientras encuentras la solución. Saludos.